# Extremize function in 4D space (minimize with respect to two variables, maximize with respect to other two variables) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, minimization, saddle

Using MATLAB, I am trying to find a saddle point of a function in 4D space. More specifically, the function is f(x,y,z,w) and I need to find its minima with respect to x and y and maxima with respect to z and w. In other words, the saddle point in 4D space is a minimum in x and y and a maximum in z and w. The variables x, y, z, and w are constrained within respective domains.

I have tried using fmincon but to no avail. The function f(x,y,z,w) surely must have a saddle point in the domain in which it is defined. What I have been doing is first using fmincon to minimize f with respect to x and y, and then use fmincon in a next step to minimize -f with respect to z and w, and then iterate. I also tried using fmincon to minimize f(x,y,z0,w0)-f(x0,y0,z,w), where (x0,y0,z0,w0) is a starting point or one calculated from a previous iteration. The latter method (I know it is quite inefficient as there is no proper weights involved) also did not work.

I would be very grateful if you guys had any ideas of how to make this work. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 3**:
One problem could be the constrained optimization algorithm. If you have just one saddle point, the alterning algorithm should do the trick, so the problem could come from the constraint.

Try the Nelder-Mead algorithm, implemented in `fminsearch`, in Matlab, which optimizes without constraints. Then check if the solution respects your contraints. If the constraints are not respected, penalize the objective function with a non respect of constraints (don't forget to change the sign of the penalization when you minimize and then maximize).

---

You could invert the effect of x and y, so maximizing the function on (-x,-y,z,w).

Rewrite your objective as: `g(x,y,y,z)=f(-x,-y,z,w)` and maximize g.

**Edit 2:** first method useless and already tried

If you think about the optimization problem, trying to minimize *and* maximize at the same time (on the same step) doesn't make much sense.

Trying to think about saddle point detection, a solution might be a two-step process:

1. Minimize the function on the domain (x,y) starting from (x0,y0,z0,w0)
2. Once you arrive at a convergence on say, (x1,y1), minimize the function on the domain (z,w) starting from (x1,y1,z0,w0)

Repeat until convergence/optimality condition.

**Edit:** I didn't visualize it in 4 dimensions, but it makes sense with a function z = f(x,y)

Comment: In fact, as I mention in the original post, that is something I did do, but it unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: My bad. Did you specify the gradient/Hessian to Matlab fmincon?

Comment: No I can't do that as there is no analytical expression for the gradient.

Comment: Your first suggestion of maximizing on (-x,-y,z,w) would not work, because the hessians of f(x) with respect to x and -x have the same sign, and so if you maximize with respect to one you automatically maximize with respect to the second.

Comment: how can Hf(x) and Hf(-x) have a same sign? And by re-reading your question: are you sure a saddle point exist? That would explain the failure of your first methods in the first place.

Comment: If f(x) is even for example. Like I mentioned, I am confident there is a saddle point as for a special case of my function there is an analytical expression that allows you to calculate the point (x,y,z,w) that gives your a saddle point, but still there I am facing problems to get it numerically. Anyway, thanks for trying.